# OAuth PHP lib - Twitter Token Request fails

Tags: php, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to request a token from Twitter using this PHP library: http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/ But it doesn't work, I get "Failed to validate oauth signature and token".

My code:

```
//http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/OAuth.php
require 'OAuth.php';

$key = 'XXXXXX';
$secret = 'XXXXXX';
$consumer = new OAuthConsumer($key, $secret);
$sig_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1;

$api_endpoint = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token';

$parameters = array('oauth_callback'=>'oob');

$req = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, null, "POST", $api_endpoint, $parameters);
$sig_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
$req->sign_request($sig_method, $consumer, null);

$ch = curl_init($req->to_url());
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: http://blainegarrett.com/2009/07/14/failed-to-validate-oauth-signature-and-token-on-twitter-oauth-check-your-cloc/

Comment: I have tried it on 2 different servers, the time seems to be OK as far as I can see..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to do the request_token call as a GET request not a POST:

```
$req = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, null, "GET", $api_endpoint, $parameters);
```

I tested this and it appears to work to get a token from my own application.

You also might want to take a look at Abraham's Twitter OAuth library, makes implementation a whole lot easier.

https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth